# How can I implement a !leaveguild <guildID> command (that leaves the specified guild) into my Discord (discord.js) bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to implement a !leaveguild  command that leaves the Discord guild with the specified ID. I'm quite new to discord.js and StackOverflow so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `guild.leave()` for that

```js
if (!args[0]) return message.reply('enter a guild ID')
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(args[0])
if (!guild) return message.reply('that is not a valid guild ID')
guild.leave()
```

Comment: Hello, this code always gives me "that is not a valid guild ID", how do I solve such issue? Edit: Yes the guild ID is valid.

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using? Also are you sure the guild ID is correct?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that the guild ID is correct. I am using discord.js v12.

Comment: It is now saying "ReferenceError: args is not defined", how do I fix this?